# LINQ expression instead of nested foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So i have List whose each element is a string array

```
List<string[]> TokenList = new List<string[]>();
```

I want to display each element in the array for every array in the list. and for that i use a nested foreach loop.

```
foreach (var temp in pro.TokenList)
        {
            foreach (var s in temp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```

Now i am trying to use LINQ in my programs and i was wondering what kind of LINQ query would be used to achieve the same desired result.

Answer (score 8):

I'd rather keep it simple:

```
// select all sub-strings of each TokenList into 1 big IEnumerable.
var query = pro.TokenList.SelectMany(item => item);

// display all strings while iterating the query.
foreach(var s in query)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

It's funny that people combine many statements, but it will be less readable.

Comment: That has the advantage over the `string.Join` solutions of not bringing all of the strings into memory at the same time; it streams them to the output, thus resulting in earlier items being seen earlier, rather than waiting for the last item to be processed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    pro.TokenList.SelectMany(s => s)
));
```

Or,

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    from arr in pro.TokenList
    from s in arr
    select s
));
```

Comment: ummm appreciate the answer but could it be in the form of a query ?

Comment: @WinCoder: Queries can only be used to _query_ data, not take side-effects.  Or do you mean query comprehension syntax as opposed to direct extension method calls?

Comment: yup query comprehension syntax

Comment: @WinCoder: Here you go.

Comment: ahhh that's better now to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    pro.TokenList.SelectMany(s => s)
));
```

This should work. If it doesn't add a comment :)

Answer (score -2):

```
pro.TokenList.ForEach(temp => Array.ForEach(temp, Console.WriteLine));
```

However not much LINQ here ;), as noted in the comments, just more concise :) Also, as noted by Servy under the other answer - this also has the advantage of not joining and storing all the strings in memory again.